# Attaching DB to SQL Server just after installation

Tags: sql-server, vb.net

Just after installing my application, I need to attach my DB to SQL server.  I am using following code for it.

```
Dim cmd As New SqlCommand()
    Dim vrMyConString As String = "Data Source=.\SQLExpress; INITIAL CATALOG=master; uid=sa; pwd=sa;"
    Dim conn As System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection = New SqlConnection(vrMyConString)
    cmd.CommandText = "sp_attach_db 'e:\dbTest.mdf', 'e:\dbTest.ldf'"
    ' conn.ConnectionString = "Data Source=.\SQLExpress; INITIAL CATALOG=master; uid=sa; pwd=sa;"
    conn.Open()
    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure
    cmd.Connection = conn
    cmd.executenonquery()
```

It returns an error:
"Login failed for user 'sa'. The user is not associated with a trusted SQL Server connection."

Please advise what do I need to do.
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Usually this is because, by default, mixed authentication mode is disabled. If it is, make sure your login credentials are correct.

Here is a link that covers how to enable mixed authentication http://support.webecs.com/KB/a374/how-do-i-configure-sql-server-express-to-enable-mixed.aspx

Comment: Login etc. all done.....

Now it gives error on  cmd.executenonquery()
Could not locate entry in sysdatabases for database 'sp_attach_db 'e:\dbTest'. No entry found with that name. Make sure that the name is entered correctly.

Comment: @FurqanSehgal probably because your `CommandType` is `StoredProcedure` but your `CommandText` is written as `CommandType.Text` Try changing your `cmd.CommandType` to `CommandType.Text` and see if it works. Then break out your proc parameters in code like this example http://www.macronimous.com/resources/calling_stored_procedures_from_ASP.NET_and_VB.NET.asp

Comment: @FurqanSehgal This might be a good candiate for a new question since the comments section is a bit cramped for troubleshooting. I'd say the original question "why login fails for new install" is answered. Please post a new question with the code and error.